# Trying to call python file from java

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to run a python file from java.

I have tried

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "pythonfile.py");
Process p = pb.start();
```

but that didn't work.  No errors were given, but the file does not run.

I also tried

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python pythonfile.py");
```

And got the same thing.  No errors, but the file does not run.

Although it shouldn't matter, this is the .py file I am trying to run:

```
 import winsound
 Freq = 1500 # Set Frequency To 1500 Hertz
 Dur = 500 # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
 winsound.Beep(Freq,Dur)
 print "this file ran!!!"
```

Nothing is printed and no noise is heard.  For various reasons, I am unable to use Jython, so please focus on this problem.  Thanks!

Solution:  As pointed out by Rahul Jha, my problem was that I had my python file in the incorrect folder.  Thank you!!

Comment: Is your Java program running in the directory that contains `pythonfile.py`? Also, `Freq` and `Dur` look pretty messed up.

Comment: Yes.  The python file is in my src folder.
I also double checked the frequency and duration are correct.  I just fixed the typo I had in the comments if that was what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BufferedReader to show your output.

```
import java.io.*;
class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "python Test.py ");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println(in.readLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

}

and my python file is Test.py

```
print "Hello World Python.";
```

Comment: I have been using NetBeans

Comment: put your pyton outside of src folder.

Comment: if your python file is inside of src you will get output null in eclipse and netbeans.

Comment: put  it in the same folder in which your src folder is.

Comment: @t9toqwerty I am facing the same problem with Eclipse IDE. I have given the absolute path of the python script while making exec call, but still it doesn't work. Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the sound isn't working, but you're not seeing any printed output because you aren't directing the process's output stream anywhere.

Try calling [`inheritIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--). A simple example:

```
new ProcessBuilder("echo", "Hello").inheritIO().start()
```